# Error vbar_stack in Bokeh Python

Tags: python, bokeh

I am a newbie in Bokeh, I want to try vbar_stack in Bokeh and follow the code in their documentation following below:

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("stacked.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
colors = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar_stack(years, x='fruits', width=0.9, color=colors, source=source,
             legend=[value(x) for x in years])

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

show(p)
```

I got this error after run the code:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-49fb8bdc8de2> in <module>()
     20            toolbar_location=None, tools="")
     21 
---> 22 p.vbar_stack(years, x='fruits', width=0.9, color=colors, source=source,
     23              legend=[value(x) for x in years])
     24 

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'vbar_stack'
```

I have tried to upgrade my bokeh to Ver. 0.12.10 (newest), however it did not work.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure that you run that code with the upgraded Bokeh? Try to add `import bokeh; print(bokeh.__version__)` somewhere along with other import - what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Bokeh is too old (the version you are using is from before `vbar_stack` was added). You need to update to a newer version. If you think you are already at a new enough version then it is likely you have some confusion between multiple virutalenv or conda environments, and are not loading the version of Bokeh you intend. Alternatively, you have some kind of install corruption (delete everything bokeh-related in `site-packages` and reinstall).